# jQuery modify LI text

Tags: jquery, selector

I have simple UL

```
<ul id=ABC>
<li>AAABBBCCC</li>
<li>BBBBB</li>
</ul>
```

I need to have JavaScript function using jQuery. This function will take one argument, as such if BB is entered as the argument, it should update above list to be something like

```
<ul id=ABC>
<li>AAA*BB*BCCC</li>
<li>*BB*BBB</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea? thanks in advance!

Comment: It should replace only the first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function liReplace(replacement) {
    $("#ABC li").each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.html(t.html().replace(replacement, "*" + replacement + "*"));
    });
}
```

Comment: Would that be `$(this).html(...`?

Comment: @xtofl -- ah yes thanks. It's late, probably shouldn't be answering :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring.replace('BB','*BB*');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t
.children(":first")
.html(
   t
   .children(":first")
   .html()
   .replace(replacement, "*" + replacement + "*")
);
```